# GraphViz dot on MediaWiki stretched out after edit

Tags: resize, mediawiki, graphviz, dot, stretched

I have edited a Graphviz diagram I made (org chart) to add some new positions in. However, when I save the edit on MediaWiki it refreshes to a stretched image. I have cleared the cache and purged the page, but it still will not resize or compress.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I get this problem sometimes, and haven't quite figured out what causes it. I've never had it persist after a page refresh though, so maybe you're seeing something different.

Comment: Are you using the [GraphViz](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:GraphViz) extension?

Answer (score 0):

Logging out and closing down the browser (after clearing the cache on the browser and purging) helped to resolve the true GraphViz image.